# Define $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \: f(x)=\lambda(A \cap[-x, x])$. Show $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq 2|x-y|$ for all $x, y \geq 0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\lambda $ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $A\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Define $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\: f(x)=\lambda(A \cap[-x, x])$.

(i) Show $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq 2|x-y|$ for all $x, y \geq 0$. Conclude that $f$ is continuous.

(ii) Determine $f(0)$ and $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$.

(iii) Assume $\lambda(A)<\infty$. Show there exists $B\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $B \subseteq A$ and $\lambda(B)=\lambda(A) / 2$.

---

(i) $|f(x)-f(y)| = |\lambda(A \cap[-x, x]) - \lambda(A \cap[-y, y])| = |0-0| $. The last "=" follows from some properties of the measure $\lambda$. Since $|f(x)-f(y)|=0$ and $0 \le 2|x-y|$ then $|f(x)-f(y) |\le 2|x-y|$. **Correct?**

(ii) $f(0)=0$ follows from properties of $\lambda$. The hard part. $A_n:= A \cap [-n,n]$. Notice $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ and that $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n = A$. So $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda(A_n)=\lambda(A)$. I just need to argue why
$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$. This I understand intuitively, **but**  I do not know the formal argument.

(iii) I can probably do this after doing (i)-(ii).

Comment: "$|0-0|$ follows from some properties of the measure"? What properties?

Comment: I have made a mistake. I know what it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

(i) Obviously $|f(x)-f(y)|\neq 0$. Use the fact that $\lambda (E\setminus F)=\lambda (E)-\lambda (E\cap F)$ whenever $\lambda (E)<\infty $.

(ii) $f$ is an increasing function.

Comment: But the problem does not say "assume $\lambda(A)<\infty$ ". So have is that allowed.

Comment: But $A\cap [-x,x]$ is finite ! (the $A$ I used, is note the same than the one in your exercise) @Xenusi

Comment: Oh, yes. because $x\in[0,\infty)$, right?

Comment: @Xenusi: yes...